# Angular - Encapsulate Lazy Style Bundle To Component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-routing

I have an angular 6 SPA application where there are 2 sections: Public & Private.
all the public components are wrapped inside PublicAppWrapperComponent using children routes and the same for the private components which are being wrapped inside PrivateAppWrapperComponent. Both sections has their own style which are being loaded in a lazy mode:

```js
[
  {
    "input": "./src/lazy-private-style.scss",
    "lazy": true,
    "bundleName": "lazy-private-style"
  },
  {
    "input": "./src/lazy-public-style.scss",
    "lazy": true,
    "bundleName": "lazy-public-style"
  }
]
```

Both style files imports many other css & scss files.
Since all the components inside PrivateAppWrapperComponent are bound to route with /private prefix and the public components to a route of /public
 I'm using a guard to load the styles

```js
export class PublicResourcesLoaderGuard implements CanActivate {
  private isLoaded: boolean;

  constructor(private readonly dynamicStyleLoader: DynamicStyleLoaderService,
    private readonly dynamicScriptLoaderService: DynamicScriptLoaderService) {

  }
  
  public async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    const LAZY_PUBLIC_STYLE_BUNDLE_NAME = 'lazy-public-style.css';
    
    if (this.isLoaded ) {
      return true;
    }
    
    this.isLoaded = true;
    await this.dynamicStyleLoader.load(LAZY_PUBLIC_STYLE_BUNDLE_NAME);
    await this.dynamicScriptLoaderService.loadMultiple(LAZY_PUBLIC_SCRIPTS);

    return true;
  }
}
```

My problem is that the public design collides with private design.
I am looking for a view to binding the lazy bundles to their specific components.
How can I do it?